# Unable to use server-side JavaScript (SJSS) in emails on Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget)

Tags: email, salesforce, crm, serverside-javascript, exacttarget

UPDATE - You can only use SJSS in automation studio and web pages, not within emails. For this you need AMPscript.

---

Original question:

I can not use any SJSS functions in emails on Marketing cloud (ExactTarget).

My email contains the following:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var de = DataExtension.Init("<data extension external key>");
var de2 = de.Rows.Retrieve();
</script>
```

and I receive the error:

```
Unable to generate preview
An error occurred when attempting to execute a Javascript block. See inner 
exception for detail.
Script: 
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var de = DataExtension.Init("<data extension external key>");
var de2 = de.Rows.Retrieve();

ListID: 0
Index: 4

Object expected: Retrieve
Line: 4 Char: 0
var de2 = de.Rows.Retrieve()

Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.
```

I can not find any documentation on this error. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
var de = DataExtension.Init("<data extension external key>");
```

returns a Data Extension using:

`Write(Stringify(de));`